# Discord.js code doesn't work sending embed messages

Tags: javascript, discord.js, embed

Discord.js code doesn't work sending embed messages

Code embed :
[image]

Error code :
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO Rich. Please include your code and error as text rather than linking to images of them.

Comment: Please avoid posting images (or worse, links to images) of code or errors. Anything text-based (code and errors) should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are using `client#channels#cache#get` which is not a valid function since client is not defined in the code block.

You need to use `member.guild.channels.cache.get('<id goes here>').send(embed);`

Comment: Don't work 
    member.guild.channels.cache.get('799307957414002779').send(embed);
                                                                                                         ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Comment: Make sure your channel ID is correct, because the code above is right, I see your problem now, change the `let guild = ....`  to another variable name as I think it is conflicting

Comment: @RichBiach if my answer worked please mark it as correct by clicking the tick